# Postback doesn't occur while using jQuery validations in MVC4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have used jQuery Validation in my MVC4 form. Validations work fine but postback doesn't occur. When i remove the jQuery part, posback takes place correctly. But i want both of them to work simultaneously. Below is my code :

MVC Form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "studentForm" }))
{
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                First Name:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Last Name:
            </td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Gender:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Male") Male
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Gender, "Female") Female
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Email Id:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EmailId)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Phone No:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.PhoneNo)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Educational Qualification:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EducationalQualification)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Address:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Address)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Date Of Birth:
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DateOfBirth)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.validator.addMethod("validPhoneNo", function (value, element) {

            if (!isNaN(value)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        }, 'Please enter only digits');

        $('#studentForm').validate({
            debug: true,
            rules: {
                FirstName: {
                    required: true
                },
                LastName: {
                    required: true
                },
                EmailId: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                },
                Gender: {
                    required: true
                },
                DateOfBirth: {
                    required: true
                },
                PhoneNo: {
                    required: true,
                    maxlength: 10,
                    validPhoneNo: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                FirstName: {
                    required: 'First Name is Required'
                },
                LastName: {
                    required: 'Last Name is Required'
                },
                EmailId: {
                    required: 'Email Id is Required',
                    email: 'Please enter a valid email Id'
                },
                Gender: {
                    required: 'Gender is required'
                },
                DateOfBirth: {
                    required: 'Date Of Birth is required'
                },
                PhoneNo: {
                    required: 'Phone No is required',
                    maxlength: 'Phone no cant be more than 10 digits'
                }
            }
        });


        $('#DateOfBirth').datepicker();



    });

</script>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Home/

        public ActionResult Home()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Home(Home model)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Display", model);

        }

        public ActionResult Display(Home model)
        {

            return View(model);

        }

    }
```

And here is my Model:

```
public class Home
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
        public string EmailId { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNo { get; set; }
        public string EducationalQualification { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well..the jquery validator works on the client side and will prevent the post back from happening if the validation fails. If the jquery validation succeeds then the post back will happen.

Comment: Post back doesn't happen even when all the fields are entered correctly.

Comment: Why are you putting all the validation rules into the client side code? Normally the way to do it is put validationattributes on the properties in the Model (eg [Required]) - and by default unobtrusive validation is automatically done client side (in addition to the server side validation).

Comment: @JamesS: Okay, i will use validationattributes. Still, i wanted to know where i am wrong in using the above code.